# How to derive LDPC Generator Matrix from Parity Check Matrix 48X96 Using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, code-generation

I have generated a LDPC sparse parity check matrix for `n = 96`, `M = 48` and `k = 48` at rate of `1/2`. [Link](http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/codes/data.html#l1)  (`N = 96`,`K = 48`, `M = 48`, `R = 0.5`)

The following link will show `H` matrix declaration [H matrix declaration link](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/High-Level-Synthesis-HLS/How-to-initialize-Larger-size-and-generate-IP-in-HLS/m-p/784988)

Matlab source code for Generator Matrix:

```matlab
    function [b] = inv_GF2(A)
     %Ainv = inv_GF2(A)
     dim = size(A);
     rows = dim(1);
     cols = dim(2);
     
     for i = 1:rows
       for j = 1:rows
         unity(i,j) = 0;
       end
    
       unity(i,i) = 1;
    
     end
    
     for i = 1:rows
       b(1:rows,i) = gflineq(A,unity(1:rows,i));
     end
    
     H = [h1 h2];
     [m,n] = size(H);
    
     A(1:m,1:m) = H(1:m,1:m);
     B(1:m,1:m) = H(1:m,m+1:n);

     d = mod(inv_GF2(B)*A,2); 
     I = eye(m);
     G = [ I d'];
```

The above MATLAB code is showing incorrect result. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and format that code properly

Comment: Also, provide a [mcve]